# Don't complete resource copy transaction, if certain conditions are not met in preinstall script, but mark that package as installed in rpmdb

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have a driver package B, which I would like to get pulled in as a dependency when I fire a build plan which installs package A. A's sole purpose is to act as a wrapper package which pulls in all packages required for the system to work, as a dependency.

The driver B should only install itself on the system if it's a H/W platform else it should only mark itself as installed in db and not really complete the installation. The thing is that if B is not installed then package A which has a dependency on B, will also fail to install and hence the complete build plan fails.

And can packages have dynamic dependencies based on some condition ? Because then i can move that logic to package A to specify B as its dependency if certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do what you want (at least not directly).

The closest you can probably get is to have package `B` install a tarball of the driver files/etc. and then check (in `%post` or similar) whether the platform is appropriate and extract only if it is.

That being said I don't recommend that path at all (and if you do want to do that I believe you will want to mark all those files as `%ghost` files so that RPM at least knows about them).

I would sooner suggest that if the drivers are (or can be made) harmless on the non-H/W platform that you just let them install and ignore it. Alternatively, you could use a "virtual" `Provides` from the `B` package as the requirement in the `A` package and create a second version of `B` that does not include the files (only the `Provides`) and then have multiple installation repositories that are used as appropriate.

RPM dependencies are stored in the package header and have no support for anything nearly as complicated as conditional assertions (that I'm aware of at least).